# Swift iOS: dyld: dyld_sim cannot be loaded in a restricted process

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, nstask, dyld

I'm making an iOS app for jailbroken devices running iOS 12 or newer.

I need my app to run a command line command, so to achieve that I use a [custom Objective-C header file](https://pastebin.com/V28wJq6A) which creates the object NSTask and everything it needs, and then, using Bridging Headers I expose it to Swift.

So, to run a task I use the following function:

```
func task(launchPath: String, arguments: String...) -> NSString {
    let task = NSTask.init()
    task?.setLaunchPath(launchPath)
    task?.arguments = arguments

    // Create a Pipe and make the task
    // put all the output there
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task?.standardOutput = pipe

    // Launch the task
    task?.launch()
    task?.waitUntilExit()

    // Get the data
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    return output!
}
```

And call it like this:

```
installPackage = task(launchPath: "/usr/bin/dpkg", arguments: "-i", packageID, "control")
```

I noted that this wasn't doing anything, so I wanted to check what was the command really doing.

To do this, I printed `installPackage`.
This should have printed the dpkg command output, but instead, it printed the following:

```
print(installPackage)

~> dyld: dyld_sim cannot be loaded in a restricted process
```

I've read that to fix this you need to turn off **Thread Sanitizer** or change the **Build Configuration** to **Release**, but it keeps showing the same message.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed your app in `/Applications/YourAppName.app` on the device? It seems you're facing regular app sandbox restrictions, because it's installed in `/private/containers/...` by Xcode just like regular apps would be.